# How can I change password for multiple credentials in Windows Vault (a.k.a. Credential Manager)?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, credentials-manager

My Windows 7 laptop is not joined to my company's Active Directory domain. However, I connect to a number of resources on the domain, including intranet sites, file shares, and TFS. Every three months, my company makes me change my password.

I've discovered that Windows 7 has a Credential Manager where I can go in and edit stored passwords. However, by the time I change my password I have at least a dozen different credentials to edit. Note that each credential has the same "domain\user" format user name.

**Is there a way to change the password for every credential with the same user name?**

I think the problem is more acute with file shares and TFS, where I seem to just get denied access. With intranet sites I at least get prompted by Internet Explorer to change my password (albeit repeatedly for each one I access).

Comment: Could you just add a domain credential for `*.companydomain.tld`? I'm sure Windows supports this.

Comment: @grawity yes - that works! If you put this as answer I'll give you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For completeness, you can manage credentials at the command line or in batch script with `cmdkey.exe` (located in %windir%\system32).

For example, to add (or update) the credentials on `server.domain.tld`:

`cmdkey.exe /add:server.domain.tld /user:username /pass:password`

or for the entire domain:

`cmdkey.exe /add:*.domain.tld /user:username /pass:password`

`/user` can also take `domain\username` or `username@domain`

Instead of opening Windows Vault you could run a simple batch script that would prompt you for your new password:

```
set /p pw=Enter your new password:
cmdkey.exe /add:*companydomain.tld /user:myusername /pass:%pw%
```

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is interested in reading and writing to it from PowerShell or C#, here's a link to a script that does it:

[PowerShell Credentials Manager: CredMan.ps1](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde)

The PowerShell script accesses the API via inline C# that utilizes Pinvoke.