# Link Apps to share password credentials (sort of SSO)

Tags: windows, windows-10, password-management, credentials, credentials-manager

My OneDrive for Business, Office365, Email, WiFi and certain other applications use the same username and password for login (that of my university account).

The issue is I have to change the password every 90 days, and once I have done that on my university account, I have to manually update the password on each of this application. This can be stressful and sometimes apps do no function well if I forget to do this on time (for example, an app may keep trying to log in using the correct username and old password, and after a number of tries, I may be banned by the university authentication server, thus affecting other apps).

I think OneDrive, Office365 and some other apps store the password in a sort of way in the Windows Credential Manager. Is there any way to link these so that I only have to change the password once for all apps?

**EDIT:**
I tried using Credential Manager as set forth [here](https://superuser.com/questions/380596/how-can-i-change-password-for-multiple-credentials-in-windows-vault-a-k-a-cred) but OneDrive for Business still required me to put in a password and created a new generic credential in the vault. How do I "unify" everything?

Comment: You don't specify what version of Windows.  In any case, you can use the built-in Credential Manager in Windows for most of the Microsoft products.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have tagged it Windows 10 now. Thanks. I tried using Credential Manager as set forth [here](https://superuser.com/questions/380596/how-can-i-change-password-for-multiple-credentials-in-windows-vault-a-k-a-cred) but OneDrive for Business still required me to put in a password and created a new generic credential in the vault.